# Exception using fileupload on Tomcat5

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload, genexus

I'm trying to develop and uploader servlet, and for that I'm using fileupload librery from Apache. I'm running my servlet on: Server Version: Apache Tomcat/5.5.36
Servlet Version: 2.4 JSP Version: 2.0

I'm getting the next exception and I have no idea what do more:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.isMultipartContent(Lorg/apache/commons/fileupload/RequestContext;)Z
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(ServletFileUpload.java:71)
photoUploader.processRequest(photoUploader.java:48)
photoUploader.doPost(photoUploader.java:87)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

It seems to be a trouble with the imports, but I'm not sure.

This is the code I'm using for doing that:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class photoUploader extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        final String RUTA_LOCAL_APP = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet photoUploader</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet photoUploader at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("<h5>Versiones del Servlet: M->" + getServletContext().getMajorVersion() + 
                        "| m->" + getServletContext().getMinorVersion() + "</h5>");
            out.println("<h5>Adjunta MultipartContent?: " + ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request) + "</h5>");
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.println("<h3>Excepción: </h3>" + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }
```

When I check if isMultipartContent `out.println("<h5>Adjunta MultipartContent?: " + ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request) + "</h5>");`  is when I get the error.

Im sure I've got *.jar in right place:

```
Webapp Content:
├───CSS
│       Stuff
│
├───JS
│   │   jquery-1.11.2.js
│   │
│   └───jquery-ui
│       │   Stuff
│       │
│       ├───external
│       │   └───Stuff
│       │
│       └───images
│               Stuff
│
├───META-INF
│       MANIFEST.MF
│
├───static
│   │   Stuff
│   │
│   └───imagenes
│           Stuff
│
└───WEB-INF
    │   web.xml
    │
    ├───classes
    │       photoUploader.class
    │       
    │
    └───lib
            commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
            commons-io-2.4.jar
            GXClassR.jar
            iText.jar
            mysql-connector-java-3.1.13-bin.jar
            poi.jar
```

Id like to know if:

- there's any way to check that imported lib are in the right place in runtime.
- is there any trouble with version of my server (Apache Tomcat/5.5.36 Servlet Version: 2.4 JSP Version: 2.0) Some known issue I haven't read.
- the idea is to use only *.class (with servlet definition inside WEB-INF/classes) to work together with the other servlets I have. I tell you this because if I deploy the war using Tomcat Manager it works without any trouble, but inside my own App it fails. May be it's not importing libs as it should.

Any help/idea is welcome, I've tried all solutions proposed on StackOverflow and no one worked for me, so I'm asking again.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got it. I work with Genexus, and inside `GXClassR.jar` (library used by Genexus) there was another instance of the same *.class (aparently older and out of date). I deleted it and leaved only the new one and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. We will update or remove that class asap.